# List of changes to Firefox extension requirements?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, compatibility

As you know Firefox extensions can get broken when newer versions of FF are released, i.e. Firefox makes changes to extension requirements.

Is there a list/resource/forum board etc, that describes what these changes are?

Especially since many of the "getting started" tutorials were written along time ago. now it is hard to know which requirements have changed and which are still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each significant update is listed in the release notes for developers at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases. This includes information for web and add-on developers.

The best way to stay up-to-date is to follow the blog at https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/, which frequently publishes about changes affecting Add-on compatibility, AMO statistics and so on.